# How to make a web script to retrieve automotive model years for 1,800 models from Wikipedia or elsewhere?

Tags: fetch, wikipedia

I've compiled the make, model, and trim of 1,800 different automobiles, but have had no luck finding a database of their model years. Is there a way to use devtools console in Chrome or FF Dev to fetch each one and store them in json?

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes it's possible, but it depends how the data is structured on Wikipedia. If it's in a specific field of the infobox at the top, it'd be trivial, but if you are needing to fetch it from the middle of a paragraph, that'll be tricky. https://www.wikidata.org should in theory have this kind of information, but things aren't necessarily complete.